# Sending application error message to your email

Tags: java, email, properties

I want to send a message to notify the user when there is an exception occur in your application. I am wondering what is the best way to do it in Java?

In my program, I have a properties files call mail.properties. I declared some of the properties in this file. I successfully read the properties from my properties file. Now I need to detect an error in my program and send an error message to my email account

mail.properties

```
smtpServer = smtp.gmail.com
smtpUsername = myemail@gmail.com
smtpPassword = 123456
smtpPort = 465
```

In my main method, I have declared my properties file. I call this main.java

```
public class main{

       private static String smtpServer;
       private static String smtpUsername;
       private static String smtpPassword;
       private static String smtpPort;

    public static void main (String[] args){


       //Method for initialize the properties
       initialize();

       //Code go here (Sending message and stuff)

      try{



     }

       catch(Exception ex)
       {

       }

    }


    private static void initialize() throws Exception{

      //loadProperties is where I check and get the properties file (no need to worry about it
      Properties props = PropertiesUtil.loadProperties("mail.properties");

      smtpServer = props.getProperty("smtpServer")
      smtpUsername = props.getProperty("smtpUsername")
      smtpPassword = props.getProperty("smtpPassword")
      smtpPort = props.getProperty("smtpPort")


     }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by error? Do you mean exception? If that's the case use try/catch where you think an error can occur and send the exception stack trace to the desired mail

Comment: yes, sorry for the unclear topic, I mean an exception occur

Comment: In that case, that's what you need to do use try/catch

Comment: I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Practice is create a RuntimeException, throw that exception upto top of the layer. at the top of the layer pass exception to the utility and send the exception message as email body.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want notify error only when they are RuntimeException subclases because they indicate an unexpected error that you are not controlling.

Exception is too spread and you will notify to the user with anything error condition. I suggest you catch RuntimeException and only some checked exceptions.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Job job = new Job();
            job.doSomething();
       } catch (RuntimeException | MustNotifyException re) {
           sendMessage();
       }
   }

   public static void sendMessage() {

   }
}

class Job {

    void doSomething() throws MustNotifyException {

    }
}

class MustNotifyException extends Exception {

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am wondering how can I initialize the connection to my email? Should I use a Session or something like this in order to connect my application to my email address?

Comment: If you need to connect to smtp server, then you must use javamail api https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

Comment: Thanks. But my question now is, how can I store an exception message that displayed in my console, so that I can send it to my email address?